# scalaks-bootstrap: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at scalajsenv.js:29

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I try to make a simple **scalajs** + **scalajs-bootstrap** application, but there is few documentation on how to set up the skeleton. The scalajs-bootstrap project has an example, but the build.sbt file is very big and it contains both the source code of the scalajs-bootstrap and the example itself.

I tried creating a new project with only the bootstrap4 example, but when I open the index.html page on the browswer, it complains with

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at scalajsenv.js:29`

This is my current set-up:

project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.20")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.karasiq" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "1.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.13.0")
```

build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.karasiq" %%% "scalajs-bootstrap-v4" % "2.3.5"

npmDependencies in Compile += "jquery" -> "3.2.1"
npmDependencies in Compile += "bootstrap" -> "4.1.1"

mainClass in Compile := Some("com.karasiq.bootstrap4.test.frontend.BootstrapTestApp")
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
version in webpack := "4.28.4"
emitSourceMaps := false
```

This is the source code of scalajs-bootstrap4 libray and example:
https://github.com/Karasiq/scalajs-bootstrap

This is my complete minimal example, which fails with the `exports is not defined` error:
https://github.com/dportabella/scalajs-bootstrap4-examples

How to modify plugins.sbt and/or build.sbt to make this project work?

---

**Solution**

project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.28")
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.13.0")
```

build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.karasiq" %%% "scalajs-bootstrap-v4" % "2.3.5"

npmDependencies in Compile += "jquery" -> "3.2.1"
npmDependencies in Compile += "bootstrap" -> "4.1.1"

mainClass in Compile := Some("com.karasiq.bootstrap4.test.frontend.BootstrapTestApp")
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
version in webpack := "4.28.4"
emitSourceMaps := false
```

full example: 
https://github.com/dportabella/scalajs-bootstrap4-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, you need to:

- Add the following lines to your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.25")
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.13.1")
```

- Enable both `ScalaJSPlugin` and `ScalaJSBundlerPlugin` in your `build.sbt`
- Add the following configuration to your `build.sbt`:

```scala
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
version in webpack := "4.28.4"
emitSourceMaps := false
```

Finally, run `fastOptJS::webpack` to create the packed JS file.

Note that the packed JS file needs to be referenced in the `index.html` - not the compiled JS file!

I hope this helps.

Comment: the issue `npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied` was solved by deleting my ~./npm folder, and running sbt again. However, it still fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at scalajsenv.js:29` when opening the index.html file on the browser.

Comment: it works now; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57203275/280393
However it fails with plugin ch.epfl.scala:sbt-scalajs-bundler from 0.15.0 (instead of 0.13.0). any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using [sbt-web-scalajs](https://github.com/vmunier/sbt-web-scalajs) like me see:
https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/getting-started.html#sbt-web