# sbt looks for another version of the requested dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.28")
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.15.0")
```

build.sbt (simplified)

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.karasiq" %%% "scalajs-bootstrap-v4" % "2.3.5"
```

But it fails as follows:

```
$ sbt fastOptJS::webpack
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.karasiq#scalajs-bootstrap-v4_sjs1.0.0-M7_2.12;2.3.5: not found
```

Why is it looking for `scalajs-bootstrap-v4_sjs1.0.0-M7` instead of `scalajs-bootstrap-v4`?

The minimal project is here: https://github.com/dportabella/scalajs-bootstrap4-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following versions in `project/plugins.sbt` which mimics what is in scalajs-bootstrap's [plugins.sbt](https://github.com/Karasiq/scalajs-bootstrap/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt)

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.20")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.karasiq" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "1.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.13.0")
```

and in `build.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.karasiq" %%% "scalajs-bootstrap-v4" % "2.3.5"
```

Note the downgrade of Scala to 2.12.6 from 2.12.8.

Comment: Why is so? their README.md tells to use `%%%`. https://github.com/Karasiq/scalajs-bootstrap

If I replace it with '%%', then it fails with `BootstrapTestApp.scala:12:30: object jquery is not a member of package com.karasiq.bootstrap`.

And adding `libraryDependencies += "com.github.karasiq" %% "scalajs-bootstrap-jquery" % "2.3.5"` fails with  `unresolved dependency: com.github.karasiq#scalajs-bootstrap-jquery_2.12;2.3.5: not found`.

And adding the later with '%%%' fails also with: `unresolved dependency: com.github.karasiq#scalajs-bootstrap-jquery_sjs1.0.0-M7_2.12;2.3.5: not found`

Comment: Thanks. running `sbt fastOptJS` it now compiles, but when opening the index.html page on the browser it complains on `scalajsenv.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at scalajsenv.js:26`. Running `fastOptJS::webpack` then sbt complains on `npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/david/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ba/5e/cb33f007c3088b236318edb33f550733ae839cc0b1dc574b40c344eb50d4'`. any idea?

Comment: I've updated the repo with the new problem: https://github.com/dportabella/scalajs-bootstrap4-examples

Comment: @DavidPortabella There seems to be a typo in the bundle path in `index.html`: https://github.com/dportabella/scalajs-bootstrap4-examples/pull/1

Comment: I upgraded Scala from 2.12.6 to 2.12.8, upgraded plugin sbt-scalajs from 0.6.20 to 0.6.28 and removed plugin com.github.karasiq:sbt-scalajs-bundler, and it works.

Comment: Why the downgrade of plugin ch.epfl.scala:sbt-scalajs-bundler from 0.15.0 to 0.13.0? (it indeed fails with 0.15.0)